# Javascript getters: calling a getter from within another getter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build out a dateData object, it looks something like this:

```
  const [dateData] = React.useState({
    dateObject: new Date(),
    get currentYear() {
      return this.dateObject.getFullYear();
    },
    get currentMonth() {
      return this.dateObject.getMonth();
    },
    get firstDayOfMonth() {
      return this.dateObject(this.currentYear, this.currentMonth).getDay();
    }
  });
```

The code crashes at `get firstDayOfMonth()`, saying that `this.currentYear is not a function`, but the getters `get currentYear()` and `get currentMonth()` correctly return the expected data, so I know they're accessing `dateObject` correctly.

Is what I am trying to accomplish not feasible in Javascript?

[image: Edit vibrant-tereshkova-0esui]

Comment: return new Date(this.currentYear,this.currentMonth).getDay();

Comment: Where did you get the idea for this use of `React.useState` hook from?

Answer (score 2):

There is an error on your code.
Please update it as follows.

```
const [dateData] = React.useState({
    dateObject: new Date(),
    get currentYear() {
      return this.dateObject.getFullYear();
    },
    get currentMonth() {
      return this.dateObject.getMonth();
    },
    get firstDayOfMonth() {
      return new Date(this.currentYear, this.currentMonth, 1);
    }
  });
```

Comment: `return new Date(this.currentYear...` create a new instance of `Date` here, correct? Is there a way to use the same reference that already exists in `dateObject`?

Answer (score 0):

First , let me tell you why your code is crashing.
You already called/invoked constructor function **Date** `dateObject: new Date(),` here.
Again, you are trying to invoke it in below method which is wrong and that is why your code is crashing.

```
get firstDayOfMonth() {
      return new Date(this.currentYear, this.currentMonth, 1);
    }
```

Now, what is the solution,
You can use the solutions provided in above answers by users>> **by using new Date**.

In case if you want to stick to the same date which is available in dateObject `dateObject: new Date()` then , you can try below code:

```
get firstDayOfMonth() {
  let bindedDate= Date.bind(this.dateObject)
  return new bindedDate(this.currentYear, this.currentMonth).getDay();
}
```

Comment: In this case, `return new bindedDate ..` you are still creating a new instance of the Date object, no? Then, what is the difference between this and `return new Date ...`?

Comment: @Mike, yes I am also creating new instance of Date. You will have to create a new instance, there is no doubt about it. The answer that I posted is for a scenario in which dataObject is created a while ago or dataObject is created like new Date(1995, 11, 24, 10). In these cases user needs that specific date not the new date